# Response.toString() returns io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@46320c9a instead of Response body string

Tags: gson, rest-assured

I am using GSON to serialise and deserialise JSON response while supplying as payload and mapping response to the data model.

Now, here id is auto-incremented from DB so we don't need to pass when creating payload.

JSON payload: (updateCustomer)
{"first_name":"test", "last_name":"user"}

```
public class Address {

  @SerializedName("id")
  private Integer id;

 @SerializedName("first_name")
  private String firstname;

 @SerializedName("last_name")
  private String lastname;

 ....

}
```

**Test:**

```
Response response = 
                given()
                        .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(this.requestCapture))
                         .filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter(this.responseCapture))
                         .filter(new ErrorLoggingFilter(this.errorCapture))
                         .header("Authorization", getSession().getToken())
                         .body(updateCustomer)
                .when()
                        .put(Resource.UPDATE_CUSTOMER)
                .then()
                        .extract().response();
```

**Expected Response in response instance**
{"id":2234545, "first_name":"test", "last_name":"user"}

Response.toString() returns io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@46320c9a instead of Response body string.

I've tried response.body().toString(),

```
@Expose(deserialize = false)
@SerializedName("id")
private Integer id;
```

but no luck.

Expecting the response body as the string so that I can map using GSON to Java objects to perform the validation but getting  **io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@46320c9a**

I appreciate if someone can please direct me on this issue.

Many thanks,

Comment: I think the `response()` method is giving  object form of the response which you got. Try updated answer. Hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Dipesh

Instead of `response.body().toString();`  try `response.getBody().asString();`

See the sample code I have done below and the output

Code

```
package com.restassured.framework.sample;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.response.Response;

/**
 * @author vamsiravi
 *
 */
public class RestAssuredExample {

    @Test
    public void sampleTest(){
        Response response = given().baseUri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/").and().basePath("/posts/1").when().get().thenReturn();


        System.out.println(response.body());
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());
    }

}
```

Output

```
io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@652a7737
---------------------------
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Surely I shall check it out.

Comment: Thanks, Ravi. I was using response.getBody().print() which was working as well but its more logical to use response.getBody().asString().

Answer (score 0):

```
            given()
                    .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(this.requestCapture))
                     .filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter(this.responseCapture))
                     .filter(new ErrorLoggingFilter(this.errorCapture))
                     .header("Authorization", getSession().getToken())
                     .body(updateCustomer)
            .when()
                    .put(Resource.UPDATE_CUSTOMER)
            .then()
                  .body("id", equalTo("2234545"));
```

Hamcrest matcher import:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion Veeresh.
I've tried that as well and String instance is having io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@46320c9a value instead of JSON Response

Comment: Oh you already mentioned that you tried `body().asString()`. alright. Can you try updated answer.
Source: http://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.0